# What database am I seeding from in a stretched DAG?

Tags: exchange-2010, replication, fault-tolerance, dag

I have a stretched DAG across 2 sites, with 4 copies.  One of the remote copies failed, and I issued a re-seed operation with the remote&working copy as a source.

Knowing this, I tried to work backwards, and see if Powershell is able to tell me where the data is coming from and where it's going to.  This will be useful in future troubleshooting efforts.

I ran the typical commands and couldn't get Exchange to tell me where the data is going/from/to.

**Question**

- How can an administrator determine what the source is, and target is, when one database is seeding?

Powershell:

```
[PS] C:\Scripts\Scripts\Windows>Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus db18\txexmb02 -ConnectionStatus | fl



RunspaceId                       : cf5dfdca-0148-44c7-bea1-63c29e6c6eb4
Identity                         : DB18\TXEXMB02
Name                             : DB18\TXEXMB02
DatabaseName                     : DB18
Status                           : SeedingSource
MailboxServer                    : TXEXMB02
ActiveDatabaseCopy               : nycexmb02
ActivationSuspended              : False
ActionInitiator                  : Administrator
ErrorMessage                     :
ErrorEventId                     :
ExtendedErrorInfo                :
SuspendComment                   :
SinglePageRestore                : 0
ContentIndexState                : Healthy
ContentIndexErrorMessage         :
CopyQueueLength                  : 0
ReplayQueueLength                : 97
LatestAvailableLogTime           : 7/7/2014 8:28:18 AM
LastCopyNotificationedLogTime    : 7/7/2014 8:28:18 AM
LastCopiedLogTime                : 7/7/2014 8:28:18 AM
LastInspectedLogTime             : 7/7/2014 8:28:18 AM
LastReplayedLogTime              : 7/7/2014 7:40:44 AM
LastLogGenerated                 : 1073244
LastLogCopyNotified              : 1073244
LastLogCopied                    : 1073244
LastLogInspected                 : 1073244
LastLogReplayed                  : 1073147
LogsReplayedSinceInstanceStart   : 144932
LogsCopiedSinceInstanceStart     : 124270
LatestFullBackupTime             : 7/6/2014 7:38:00 PM
LatestIncrementalBackupTime      :
LatestDifferentialBackupTime     :
LatestCopyBackupTime             : 4/8/2014 2:47:40 AM
SnapshotBackup                   : True
SnapshotLatestFullBackup         : True
SnapshotLatestIncrementalBackup  :
SnapshotLatestDifferentialBackup :
SnapshotLatestCopyBackup         : True
LogReplayQueueIncreasing         : False
LogCopyQueueIncreasing           : False
OutstandingDumpsterRequests      : {}
OutgoingConnections              :
IncomingLogCopyingNetwork        : {NYCEXMB02,Replication Network Segment}
SeedingNetwork                   :
ActiveCopy                       : False



[PS] C:\Scripts\Scripts\Windows>Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus db18\txexmb01 -ConnectionStatus | fl


RunspaceId                       : cf5dfdca-0148-44c7-bea1-63c29e6c6eb4
Identity                         : DB18\TXEXMB01
Name                             : DB18\TXEXMB01
DatabaseName                     : DB18
Status                           : Seeding
MailboxServer                    : TXEXMB01
ActiveDatabaseCopy               : nycexmb02
ActivationSuspended              : True
ActionInitiator                  : Service
ErrorMessage                     :
ErrorEventId                     :
ExtendedErrorInfo                :
SuspendComment                   : The database copy was automatically suspended due to failure item processing. At '7/
                                   6/2014 7:25:53 PM' the copy of 'DB18' on this server experienced an error that requi
                                   res it be reseeded. For more detail about this failure, consult the Event log on the
                                    server for other storage and "ExchangeStoreDb" events. The passive database copy ha
                                   s been suspended.

SinglePageRestore                : 0
ContentIndexState                : Failed
ContentIndexErrorMessage         : Catalog is dismounted externally for database {cb626758-e781-456e-85a3-ead9d2e87544}
                                   .
CopyQueueLength                  : 1073244
ReplayQueueLength                : 0
LatestAvailableLogTime           :
LastCopyNotificationedLogTime    :
LastCopiedLogTime                :
LastInspectedLogTime             :
LastReplayedLogTime              :
LastLogGenerated                 : 1073244
LastLogCopyNotified              : 0
LastLogCopied                    : 0
LastLogInspected                 : 0
LastLogReplayed                  : 0
LogsReplayedSinceInstanceStart   : 0
LogsCopiedSinceInstanceStart     : 0
LatestFullBackupTime             : 5/18/2014 6:26:07 AM
LatestIncrementalBackupTime      :
LatestDifferentialBackupTime     : 5/22/2014 3:01:46 AM
LatestCopyBackupTime             : 4/8/2014 2:47:40 AM
SnapshotBackup                   : True
SnapshotLatestFullBackup         : True
SnapshotLatestIncrementalBackup  :
SnapshotLatestDifferentialBackup : True
SnapshotLatestCopyBackup         : True
LogReplayQueueIncreasing         : False
LogCopyQueueIncreasing           : False
OutstandingDumpsterRequests      : {}
OutgoingConnections              :
IncomingLogCopyingNetwork        :
SeedingNetwork                   :
ActiveCopy                       : False
```